# WordPress Blog, only use archive for current page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I am building a WP site, which will have a News and Blog.

They will be in separate pages, One for news and one for Blog, which will be separated by categories.

So for example, I have this code on 'News', which stops the loop getting posts:

```
<?php 
    $uncat = get_cat_ID('uncategorised');
    $uncat2 = get_cat_ID('blog');

    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'category__not_in' => array($uncat, $uncat2)

      );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
      <a style="color:#333; text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="postsize">
          <div class="leftfloat" style="float: left; padding-right:20px;">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'faqposts')); ?>

          </div>
          <div class="contentfaq">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
              <span class="entry-date-blue"><strong><?php echo get_the_date('d/m/y'); ?></strong></span>

              <?php $trimexcerpt = get_the_excerpt();

              $shortexcerpt = wp_trim_words( $trimexcerpt, $num_words = 10, $more = '… <br/> <a href="">Read More ...</a>' ); 

              echo '<a style="color:#333; text-decoration:none;" href="' . get_permalink() . '"><p>' . $shortexcerpt . '</p></a>'; 

              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
  </div>
```

This works fine, but I also have 'Archives' on the right hand side, which filters by date posted. The issue is, this will get posts from News AND blog, which defeats the idea of splitting them up.

Is there a way to split these up, so if the user clicks 'March 2015' on the archive, it will only get the posts from this month from NEWS?

Here is my current code for Archive.php

```
     <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <!-- First, the loop checks whether any posts were discovered with the have_posts() function. -->



  <!-- If there were any posts, a PHP while loop is started. A while loop will continue to execute as long as the condition in the parenthesis is logically true. So, as long as the function have_posts() returns a true value, the while loop will keep looping (repeating). -->
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="postsize">
      <div style="float: left; padding-right:20px;">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'faqposts')); ?>

      </div>
      <h5 class="captext"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
      <span class="entry-date-orange"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
      <?php
      foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
        echo ' | ' . $category->cat_name; 
      } 
      ?>

      <p style="margin-top:10px";><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking, what are `news` and `blog`. Are they terms, categories, custom post types....? Also, if I understand you correctly, this is actually a very big question to answer, as you will most probably be better of writing your own widget and adding parameters in the URL to serve as referers. IMHO, as I read this, `news` and `blog` should be custom post types

Comment: Hi Pieter :)

News and Blog just pull through recent posts. The Archive pulls through recent posts from a certain date and also from popular tags

Comment: Ok, but again, what is `news` and `blog`. Reread my first comment

Comment: Apologies, they are just .php files, being used as page templates for a WordPress page

Comment: So, you are using news page to display what exactly and blog page to display what exactly

Comment: I am using the news page to display posts with the category 'News' and blog to display posts with 'blog' as categories, does this make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78387/discussion-between-jonathan-and-pieter-goosen).

Comment: Ok, all of that makes sense now, that is info that should be in your question :-). I cannot chat, I'm on my phone, and it stuffs around with chat. You definitely need a lot of work here, IMO, write your own custom widget. As for filtering your archive page, you will need to use some kind of referer, and then use that to filter the archive page via `pre_get_posts`

Comment: WOW. I am so sorry! I have been reading the wrong Question!!!

Your answer makes sense now! I was looking at this question!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356122/displaying-search-term-tag-archive-in-wordpress/30356617#30356617

Comment: Aha, you had me really confused here

Comment: Apologies, and thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will echo list

```
    <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>
```

full example code

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Archives
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">

 <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>

   </div><!-- #content -->
 </div><!-- #container -->

 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: ref [check codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index)

Comment: I think you may have mis-read the question. 

I need the Archives.php page to decipher whether the page it has just came from was from News or Blog