# Displaying search term (Tag/Archive) in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I am currently using a sidebar in WordPress, and displaying 'Archive' and 'Popular Tags' in the side column.

For Example - Archive code

```
  <div class="populartags">
    <?php
    $tags = get_tags();
    $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
      $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

      $html .= "<a style='color:#333;' href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
      $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
    ?>
  </div>
```

This displays any tags which have been used on a post. 
I also have Archive (Dates) -

```
<?php wp_get_archives(); ?>
```

These pages, go to archive.php, which is great.
What I am tyring to achieve. Is a line of text, which says

' Here are the posts for (Archive / Tag).'

So, If I viewed posts from May 2015. It would say 'Here are the posts for May 2015'

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You just want the text to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, just so they know what page results they see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit `archive.php`

Just add

```
<?php if( is_month() ) { ?> // Check if month based archive
    <?php echo 'Here are the posts for'; ?>
    <?php the_time('F Y'); 
} ?>
```

Comment: So this would display the archive date, by getting what date was pressed?   What about tags?

Comment: I have edited the code. If the archive is monthly based it will return the text.

Comment: I will need to try this first thing tomorrow. What about tags, any idea?

Comment: I am not sure if tags are categorized into dates. I have only seen monthly, yearly archives. Correct me if I am wrong. If tags are in monthly format, above should work.

Comment: Apologies.  The tags are just text, which the user can add to any post

Answer (score 0):

This displays either the date, or the tag and the number of results incase people are still looking:

```
    <?php echo 'Search Results'; ?>
    <?php echo 'Displaying ' . count($posts) . ' results for '; ?>
    <?php echo $tag ?>
    <?php if( is_month() ) { ?>
    <?php the_time('F Y'); 
  } ?>
```